# Word usage counter that ignores special characters

Tags: java, special-characters

The code I found counts special characters as unique words, thus not giving me an accurate answer. How can I integrate a special character replacer or something of that kind into my existing code?

This is the sample output I am currently getting:

[image]

What I want it to be is
" This = 1, is = 1, a = 1, Testing = 1, test = 2, How = 1, so = 1".

```
public class WordCounter {
    static void countEachWrds(String fileName, Map<String, Integer>words) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        Scanner file = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        while (file.hasNext())
        {   
            String word = file.next();
            Integer count = words.get(word);
            if (count !=null)
                count++;
            else
                count = 1;
            words.put(word, count);
        }
        file.close();
    }  
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        Map<String, Integer> words = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        countEachWrds("C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\wordCounter.txt", words);
        System.out.println(words);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could [edit] your question and post the contents of file `wordCounter.txt`? If you can, then post the contents as text and **NOT** as an image. Refer to [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Try changing the delimiter used by `Scanner`. Refer to method [useDelimiter(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter(java.lang.String))

Comment: A simple regex filter on each word might get the job done: `word = word.replaceAll("^\\W*(\\w+)\\W*$", "$1");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the delimiter in `Scanner` as `Scanner file = new Scanner(new File(fileName)).useDelimiter("\\W+")` should resolve this issue.

However, there are some more areas of improvement:

1. Refactor the method `countEachWrds` to return a new map and accept the only scanner argument.
2. Use `try-with-resources` in the `main` method when creating the scanner instance and do not close it inside `countEachWrds` as it is not its responsibility
3. Use [`Map::merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) to populate the map of word frequencies in a more concise way.
4. Create an instance of `LinkedHashMap` to keep the insertion order.

That being said the refactored method could look as follows

```java
static Map<String, Integer> countWords(Scanner scanner) {
    Map<String, Integer> words = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        words.merge(scanner.next(), 1, Integer::sum);
    }
    return words;
}

// calling from main
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("sample.txt")).useDelimiter("\\W+")) {
        Map<String, Integer> map = countWords(scanner);
        System.out.println(map);
    }
}
```

Input file:

```
This is a test.
Testing.
How test so?
```

Output:

```
{This=1, is=1, a=1, test=2, Testing=1, How=1, so=1}
```