# JUnit Test Questions to verify count of words

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, junit5

I have been trying to create a test case for JUnit 5 testing but seem to keep hitting a mental road block. Basically I have a program that counts words from a fileInputStream and then sorts them. The test cases that I have come up with would be to verify the counts of several different words but am unsure on how to implement it using JUnit 5. A clip of the code I am trying to test is shown below:

```
public class wordPopulation {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    
    FileInputStream findIt = new FileInputStream("theraven.txt");
    Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(findIt);
    
    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Integer> count = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    while (fileInput.hasNext()) {

        String nextWord = fileInput.next();

        if (words.contains(nextWord)) {
            int index = words.indexOf(nextWord);
            count.set(index,  count.get(index)+ 1);
        }
        else {
            words.add(nextWord);
            count.add(1);
        }
    }
    
    fileInput.close();
    findIt.close();

    for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); ++i) {
        Collections.sort(count, Collections.reverseOrder());

        try(FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("theraven.txt", true);
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(bw)) {
        
            out.println();
            out.println(words.get(i) + " occurred " + count.get(i) + " times ");
            
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You have implemented all the functionality inside `main` method of the class, how do you plan to apply unit testing here??

Comment: So because of the way I have the program setup I am unable to test it as is?

Comment: Well, the _currently_ implemented code reads the file by the hardcoded filename, and then rewrites its contents somehow.  So you should be able to implement a test to prepare the file with the hardcoded name, run your program as is, and then re-read the rewritten file and compare its contents to some expected value.  Imho, this is just a waste of time.   An approach to refactor the code similar to Pierre CHARLES' answer is much more appropriate.

Comment: Also, word counts is better to implement using a `Map<String, Integer>` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66920129/13279831)

Comment: @NowhereMan thank you so much for that info. I want to mention that hashmaps were never taught or mentioned in my studies which is very interesting. This just saved I dont know how much additional code and was extremely efficient. Now this should make JUnit testing much better. !

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to:

- retrieve each word from a text file and store it in a variable
- retrieve number of occurrences for each word
- sort a word list by number of occurrences

To test your code you basically need to put everything in a function that will take a file path as input, and will return the sorted list as output.

In your test scenarios you will then be able to reuse your function with multiple text files from which you exactly know the result (very simple text files with very previsible array outcomes)
You then manually build the array objects that match every file you want to test and call an assert equal function between your function output and the result you manually built.

Your tests could have an init phase where is will create the text files and a post test phase where it will delete them.

ex:
for sum(int a, int b){ return a + b;}
we do:

- assertEqual(sum(3,4),7)
- assertEqual(sum(-1,4),3)

You don't want to recode your functions into your test scenarios, you want to compare your function results with previsible outcomes.

Comment: thats right, I am starting the process now of refactoring the code. Some of the confusion is coming from how Junit 4 and Junit 5 does its testing. I wish there was an easier automated way of testing.

Comment: @JohnHendricks Great! Never forget that testing frameworks are originally tools to create readable test results, the logic to test your code will always be the same: prepare input and corresponding output/results then run your code and compare results. Trying different testing frameworks/libraries will not change what you test.